# How can I call a Supplier-based constructor for a recursive set of classes based on generic container?

Tags: java, generics, constructor, functional-programming

I have seen advice that a Supplier can be used to create an instance of a parametrized class.

E.g. Here: "[Instantiating object of type parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299998/instantiating-object-of-type-parameter/300013#300013)" or here: "[Create instance of generic type in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175/create-instance-of-generic-type-in-java/36315051#36315051)"

How to create the Supplier seems clear from the linked answers:

```
// Example of creating objects in linked answers
MyClass<StringBuilder> it = new MyClass<>(StringBuilder::new);
SomeContainer<String> stringContainer = new SomeContainer<>(String::new);
```

but how to use it for a recursive set of classes based on generic container doesn't seem to be clear.

## My problem is that this Supplier methods itself has to be called as a parameter of the constructor for each recursive class. Example:

```
class SetOf<E> {
    // Supplier-based code from SO Q #75175
    private Supplier<E> supplier;
    SetOf(Supplier<E> supplier) { this.supplier = supplier; }
    createE() { return supplier.get(); }

    addToContainer(key) {
        E value = createE(); // I assume that's how it's used?
        this.add(key, value);
    }
}
```

The problem here is that if we are building container of containers thusly:

```
class SetOfThings extends SetOf<Thing> {}
class SetOfSetsOfThings extends SetOf<SetOfThings> {}
class SetOfSetOfSetsOfThings extends SetOf<SetOfSetOfThings> {}
SetOf<SetOfSetOfSetOfThings> root = new SetOf<>(SetOfSetOfThings::new);
```

So, what we are passing to the Supplier of outer class (SetOfSetOfSetOfThings) is the reference to constructor of inner class (SetOfSetOfThings) - BUT, when that `SetOfSetOfThings()` constructor will be called, it will be called with no parameters, meaning that **there will be NO supplier for SetOfThings** set in the `SetOfSetOfThings` object! (which means we can never create SetOfThings objects).

**I suppose we can fix this 3-level chain somehow, by using Lambda syntax and passing a parameter (with value of SetOfThings::new) to SetOfSetOfThings::new in turn. But this only works because our chain is 3 levels deep - what if we have to instantiate 4-level deep chain with root class being SetOfSetOfSetsOfSetsOfThings?**

<sub>This question is a very narrow Function/Supplier specific version of my more generic earlier question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44888750/how-can-i-create-a-valid-object-in-a-recursively-generic-class) (where comments pointed to both Supplier as an idea, and the linked answer showing how to use a supplier in general - neither of which work easily in case of recursive class hierarchy).</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need some kind of supplier passed to the constructor at any level, since the `Thing` at the base level ultimately has to come from somewhere. However, you can use `Supplier<Thing>` at every level like so:

```
class SetOfThings extends SetOf<Thing> {
    SetOfThings(Supplier<Thing> supplier) {
        super(supplier);
    }
}

class SetOfSetOfThings extends SetOf<SetOfThings> {
    SetOfSetOfThings(Supplier<Thing> supplier) {
        super(() -> new SetOfThings(supplier));
    }
}

class SetOfSetOfSetOfThings extends SetOf<SetOfSetOfThings> {
    SetOfSetOfSetOfThings(Supplier<Thing> supplier) {
        super(() -> new SetOfSetOfThings(supplier));
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
SetOf<SetOfSetOfSetOfThings> root = new SetOf<>(() -> new SetOfSetOfSetOfThings(Thing::new));

SetOfSetOfSetOfThings ssst = root.createE();
SetOfSetOfThings sst = ssst.createE();
SetOfThings st = sst.createE();
Thing t = st.createE();
```

EDIT: If you're just trying to create an instance of recursive `SetOf` type, you don't need subclasses:

```
SetOf<SetOf<SetOf<SetOf<Thing>>>> root = new SetOf<>(
        () -> new SetOf<>(
                () -> new SetOf<>(
                        () -> new SetOf<>(
                                Thing::new))));
```

And with a helper method to make it look nicer:

```
public static <E> Supplier<SetOf<E>> setsOf(Supplier<E> supplier) {
    return () -> new SetOf<>(supplier);
}

SetOf<SetOf<SetOf<SetOf<Thing>>>> root = new SetOf<>(setsOf(setsOf(setsOf(Thing::new))));
```

Comment: The instance variables there are just to demonstrate that each level can create an instance of the one below it. `SetOf<SetOfSetOfSetOfThings>` will create `SetOfSetOfSetOfThings` instances. I'm not sure what else you expect it to do.

Comment: Also, just to be clear, the Thing does NOT need to be created - what need to be created are nested sets of sets of sets. E.g. I don't need supplier of Thing, at any of the levels. I need a supplier of the Set (or other container) object. Sorry for confusion

Comment: No, you need it at the `SetOfThings` level. If you're extending `SetOf<Thing>` you must call its constructor, which needs an instance of  `Supplier<Thing>`. When you define a subclass without a constructor, Java implicitly generates a no-arg constructor that calls the superclass's no-arg constructor. Since `SetOf` does not have a no-arg constructor, it isn't possible to use this, you must define a constructor in the subclass.

Comment: Updated the answer with a way to make `SetOf<SetOf<SetOf<SetOf<Thing>>>>`, in case that's what you were after.